# Artisan database Missing (but still here)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This days i had many problems with laravel. This time, when i deploy my laravel app to external server, i got a exception that says:

```
ErrorException

Undefined variable: database


    protected function getDsn(array $config)
{
    // First we will create the basic DSN setup as well as the port if it is in
    // in the configuration options. This will give us the basic DSN we will
    // need to establish the PDO connections and return them back for use.
    extract($config);
    $dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database}";
    if (isset($config['port']))
    .....
```

but this is not correct because my config database file has database index! :(

```
'mysql' => array(
                 'driver'    => 'mysql',
                    'host'      => 'localhost',
                    'database'  => 'table',
                    'username'  => 'root',
                    'password'  => 'password',
                    'charset'   => 'utf8',
                    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    'prefix'    => 'mn_',
            ),
```

The same, same file works in devel environment.

someone had this problem?

thanks!

EDIT:

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "shopitos/manager",
    "description": "Server for scripting and things",
    "authors": [{
        "name": "Leandro Bezerra",
        "email": "leandro@blogdoleos.com.br"
    }],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "evernote/evernote": "dev-master",
        "artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "dev-master",
        "orchestra/debug": "2.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.29",
        "way/generators": "2.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/events",
            "app/models",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: What Laravel version do you use? It seems that it is not the actual one https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php#L56

Comment: @delmadord The OP's code looks like it's from 4.1 (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php) or earler.

Comment: This is probably an environment issue - do you have any other environments defined? Make sure it's using the correct environment on your external server.

Comment: @delmadord Actually im using "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",

Comment: Then delete the whole `vendor/` folder and run `composer install`

Comment: @delmadord i already tried this. :(

Comment: But that is code form 4.1, you cannot use 4.2

Comment: i think someone commited composer.json wrong i'll try.

Comment: @delmadord nothing, i tried clear cache using composer clear, but this composer has a bug, then i remove manually cache. Composer install on laravel 4.1.* without good results. Same error. The same composer.json works in my devel environment. Look my composer.json above.

Comment: There is 4.1.*. You did not paste any relevant code causing the exception. So far only misleading information.